# Force using intel integrated graphic card when connected to external displayport monitor

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, displayport

I have a Lenovo T520 that has an intel HD 3000 and a Nvidia NVS 4200M graphic card.

I bought a new monitor and connected via displayport (that's the only output that the monitor supports). Problem is that the Nvidia card is handling the external monitor and I want to force it so that the intel card manages both laptop display and external monitor. How can I do that?

(the reason to not use the nvidia is that it overheats and slows down to protect itself)

Comment: I can' find a reference right now thus the comment. Unfortunately the DisplayPort on this laptop is hardwired to the NVIDIA graphics card. Goes without saying that if you disable the NVIDIA graphics card completely via BIOS Setup, you won't be able to DisplayPort at all.

Comment: @misha256 really? that seems rather odd because the laptop also comes with only the integrated intel card. in that case the displayport just doesn't work? very weird.

Comment: Yup, really, I promise. The variants that only have Intel graphics are wired up differently with integrated graphics driving all ports.  Obviously Lenovo *could* have done things better, but alas, they did it like this.

Comment: This reference will do: *A major disadvantage of this mode is that the DisplayPort will not work, because it is hardwired to the Nvidia card* https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T520#NVidia_Optimus